# How can i define a toolbar for MonacoEditor in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

I have defined a monaco editor in react js as follows:

```
                            <MonacoEditor
                                    height="200"
                                    width="500"
                                    language="html"
                                    theme="vs-light"
                                    value={htmlCode}
                                    options={editorOptions}
                                    onChange={handleEditorChange}
                                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                />
```

The problemn is this editor has no toobar to allow for Bold , italic underline etc and also any html code .

How can i add the toolbar to the editor ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have provided some code , does the Monaco editor have a toolbar where by you can make the text bold, italic , underline , etc. Also can it handle html ?